# Independence of Random Variables Equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, I know I can write $E[XY]=E[X] \cdot E[Y]$.

I think I can also write $E[X^2Y^3]=E[X^2] \cdot E[Y^3]$.

However, I don't think I can write $E[X^2]=E[X] \cdot E[X]$. Is this true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, since $X$ is dependent on itself. Moreover,
$$
E[X^2] \ge E[X]E[X] = E^2[X]
$$

Comment: Okay thank you that makes sense. I have one more question. Can I write $E[3X] = 3 \cdot E[X]$, and this doesn't depend on independence of $X$ right ?

Comment: Sure, you can view $3$ as a degenerate random variable since its value is (constant) and thus, independent of any other variable.

Comment: Okay I will accept your answer. So like $E[3X(1-Y)^2] = 3E[X] \cdot E[(1-Y)^2]$

Comment: @NikitaMazepin yes, if you have independence of $X$ and $Y$ and so independence of $3$ and $X$ and $(1-Y)^2$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the reply, I understand now.